# r - saveHTML - animation in a ioslides presentation

Tags: r, animation, knitr

I was wondering how I could embed the `saveHTML` little videos from the `animation` package (`R`) in a beamer or ioslides presentation ?

Is there a simple way to do it ?

What would you recommend ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ioslides, do something like this for the animation:

```
library(animation)
des = c("This is a silly example.\n\n", "You can describe it in more detail.", 
    "For example, bla bla...")
saveHTML({
    par(mar = c(4, 4, 0.5, 0.5))
    for (i in 1:20) {
        plot(runif(20), ylim = c(0, 1))
        ani.pause()
    }
}, img.name = "unif_plot", imgdir = "unif_dir", htmlfile = "random.html", 
    autobrowse = FALSE, title = "Demo of 20 uniform random numbers", 
    description = des, ani.width=600, ani.height=400)
```

NOTE: `ani.width=600` & `ani.height=400` are kinda important

Then do something like this for the ioslides rmarkdown:

```
---
title: "animated"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

##

<iframe src="random.html"></iframe>
```

Which should give you this:

[image]

Hacks to make the animation window larger or "full screen" are beyond the scope of this question (IMO) as those are more "ioslides quirks" (and prbly have answers on SO somewhere).

**MORE INFO**

At a commanbd prompt in the directory of the animation script file
(I called mine `random.R`), *or* ensuring you've done a `setwd()`
properly in 'random.R' itself, do:

```
Rscript random.R
```

That should make:

- a `css` directory
- a `js` directory
- a `unif_dir` directory
- a `random.html` file

The `slides.Rmd` file (what I called mine) *has* to be in the same directory
as these files when knitting.

Due to the `<iframe>` being used and the need for `random.html` to pull in other
content, the presentation will *only work* from an RStudio or web server 
context. It won't work as a standalone file on a hard drive or thumb drive.

Comment: do you know how to get rid of the display of libraries ? thanks

Comment: I'm not following that. Can you update your question with more details/screenshots?

Comment: sorry it's just a detail - when I compile my document - all the libraries I used are displayed - dont know why. Why by the way the dimensions `ni.width=600 & ani.height=400 ` are important ?

Comment: I am tried all day your example, but it is not compiling properly on my slides unfortunately. I paid attention to have all the `plots` in the same folder.